# MenuItem is not working in Android - Xamarin C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform, sqlite-net

As you can see, menu item is working properly in iOS but it's not working in android. this is my code and output :

code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
    ios:Page.UseSafeArea="true"

    x:Class="Library.Screen2Page">
    <StackLayout>
       <Label Text="Books List" FontSize="30" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
        <Label x:Name="usernametxt" FontSize="25"  TextColor="RoyalBlue" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>

         <ListView x:Name="lvItems" ItemTapped="lvItems_ItemTapped" SelectedItem="{Binding .}">
       <ListView.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>              
           
               <TextCell Text="{ Binding Title }" Detail="{ Binding Author }" TextColor="RoyalBlue" DetailColor="Black">
                     <TextCell.ContextActions>
                         <MenuItem Text="Return" Clicked="return_Clicked" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                         <MenuItem Text="Checkout" Clicked="checkout_Clicked" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                         </TextCell.ContextActions>

               </TextCell>
                             
           </DataTemplate>
       </ListView.ItemTemplate>
   </ListView>
       
         <Label x:Name="txtMessage"  BackgroundColor="LightGoldenrodYellow" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>

    </StackLayout>

    
</ContentPage>
```

output :

[image]

I am expecting to work on both devices

Comment: from the docs: "On Android, the context menu is activated by long-press on a list item."

Answer (score 0):

Context menus are accessed and displayed differently on each platform.

On `Android`, the context menu is activated by **long-press** on a list item. The context menu replaces the title and navigation bar area and `MenuItem` options are displayed as horizontal buttons.Here's the code snippet below for your reference:

```
   <ListView x:Name="listView"
                  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                  VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                            <MenuItem Text="Edit"
                                      IconImageSource="icon.png"
                                      Clicked="OnEditClicked"/>
                            <MenuItem Text="Delete"
                                      Clicked="OnDeleteClicked"/>
                        </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                        <Label Text="{Binding .}" />
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

On `iOS`, the context menu is activated by **swiping** on a list item. The context menu is displayed on the list item and MenuItems are displayed as horizontal buttons.

For more details, you can refer to [Xamarin.Forms MenuItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/menuitem).